# Can fractional D-branes be described in F-theory?

Tags: string-theory, singularities, branes

In Type IIB string theory, there can exist fractional D-branes at singularities. Additionally, F-theory is in some sense an alternative description of Type IIB string theory. So there should be an F-theory description of such fractional D-branes, but I have not been able to find any papers on this topic.

Is there an F-theory description of fractional D-branes at singularities?